# Plate 4x6+4x4+4x6

Tags: part-identification, vehicle

Does anyone know the part number for this plate? I think it's from the late 1960s or early 1970s.

I haven't been able to identify it myself via Google or by browsing BrickLink plate inventory...

[image: 1970s plate?]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That would be [781 Vehicle, Base 6 x 12](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=781).

[image]

It only came [in 3 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=781&in=S) from 1972-1975, with only [379-2 Car and Caravan](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=379-2) having it in white.

[image]

Comment: I've seen a lot of vehicle bases, but I never realized there was this much variation.